# Place content in JavaScript (HTML files)

Tags: javascript, html

How to place content (example: simple text) in JavaScript?

I need it to be like youtube, where the video is only visible on JavaScript enabled browser.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say content, do you mean title?

Comment: @cesar-lopez,

no, I mean maybe some text, some links, or video (like youtube)

Comment: Then I think andy answered your question. :-)

Comment: If Andy's answer answered your question (your comment suggests it does), please accept his answer so people don't waste their time on other interpretations. If not, can you give more information about what you're actually trying to do? David Hedlund, for instance, has provided quite a useful and thorough answer for one reasonable interpretation of this question, but I suspect it's not what you're looking to do.

Comment: @t-j-crowder, One more, I also need to put php codes in JavaScript. For example, this code: <?php print $content; ?>

Comment: @dewi: The JavaScript is running on the client (unless there's more to your setup than you've indicated). The PHP is running on the server. So you can use PHP on the server to generate JavaScript that will then be sent to the client and run there, but you can't (readily) use JavaScript on the client to generate PHP that will run on the server (and probably don't want to). What you can do is output the content into a JavaScript string variable, and then either use it or not depending on your client-side logic. But there are downsides to that (unnecessary data transfer, etc.).

Answer (score 3):

Using the noscript tag, like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.write("Hello World!")
</script>
<noscript>
Your browser does not support JavaScript!
</noscript>
```

You might also want to consider putting the script in some sort of HTML comment so that browsers that don't even know about script don't render the source code, e.g.:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
document.write("Hello World!")
//-->
</script>
```

Comment: Re: *"You might also want to consider putting the script in some sort of HTML comment so that browsers that don't even know about script don't render the source code..."* It's been more than ten years since there was any need to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You need to append a new DOM node to the DOM (Document Object Model).

The simplest one would be this:

```
var myNewNode = document.createTextNode('abc');
```

As for all more advanced nodes, you can create them as follows:

```
var myNewNode = document.createElement('div');
myNewNode.className = 'cssClass';
myNewNode.innerHTML = 'abc';
```

Something that's a little neater than setting "innerHTML", however, especially if you're adding complex content, and want to hook up events to it etc, is to add children to that node:

```
var myNewNode = document.createElement('div');

var myChildNode = document.createElement('input');
myChildNode.type = 'button';
myChildNode.value = 'Click me';

myNewNode.appendChild(myChildNode);
```

Assuming, then, that you've created `myNewNode` in any of the ways described above, you just need to locate the place in your document where you want to add the new node, and insert it:

```
document.body.appendChild(myNewNode);
```

or

```
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(myNewNode);
```